# Why does my Actions on Google bot change the user query before sending the query to Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We have built an app in "Actions on google" (AoG) and using Dialogflow and webhooks for fulfillment. Recently, when we discovered some unintended fallbacks, we turned on logs to see what is happening in the background only to discover that AoG is modifying the user query before sending it to Dialogflow.

We wonder if the parameter ***speechBiasingHints*** in AoG AppResponse is causing the user inputs to be modified on the fly?

We checked our fulfillment app and we are not modifying the user query via our webhooks. Has anyone experienced this issue with their AoG bots lately? Is it a platform wide from Google that we are not aware of?

[AoG modifies user query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sICNl.png)

Comment: Is this only happening when you use the word "this", and does it seem to be replacing "this" with something you recently mentioned?

Comment: Any pronouns really - it, they, this, he, she

Comment: Yes "this" is being replaced with something I recently mentioned, so I suspect AoG is doing some kind of implicit entity resolution